# Django queryset to order by list of item matches in one of the fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Im working on a queryset which requires a complex ordering of queryset.

here is my model.py

```
class ItemTable(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class tableA(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(ItemTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class tableB(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(ItemTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Im not sure how do I do a query on tableB to with specific items passed from the `request.body` and then match/compare the items from tableA and replace the entire items values on tableB obj with only matching queryset and order them based on the counts on the replaces items list for each obj.

Eg:

```
tableB_qs = tableB.objects.filter(items__in=["list_of_ids_from_request_body"])


items_list_from_tableA = tableA.objects.get(id=request.user).items
```

then --> Compare items_list_from_tableA with tableB_qs each object property "items".

then -->> replace the matched only ingredients to the items list for each obj in tableB qs.

then -->> Order the final qs based on the count of items for an obj in tableB qs